# How do I make a function that checks if the website is not loading (not finished loading)?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

So, I have a chrome extension and for it to work like it should, I need to make some type of if statement asking whether or not the active tab is *not loading*, please don't be confused with "finished loading".

I've already tried:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function (tabId , info) {
    if (info.status === 'complete') {
        // code
    }
});
```

but this will only execute the code when the active tab has finished loading.

If you still don't understand what I mean by "finished loading" and "not loading", I basically want it to ask if the tab's title has the loading icon or not.

If you need more information just comment on this question.

Comment: A listener is a passive thing. If you need to read the current state, use chrome.tabs.get.

Comment: Thanks, I'll do some research on that but can I have an example on this, please?

Comment: Sure, there should be lots of easily discoverable examples.

Comment: @wOxxOm | (sorry for the late response) Where can I find these examples?

Comment: Use any search site e.g. google.com, or inspect the [official demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples#search:tabs.get).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My code needed a few minor updates, here's the fixed code:

```
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(function(tabId, changeInfo, tab) {
  if (tab.active && changeInfo.status === 'complete') {
    // code to execute when the active tab has finished loading
  }
});
```

Now, this simply confirms that the tab is actually active.

To answer my question, I simply need to create a variable external from the block with a boolean value of false, and then turn it to true after the tab has finished loading. Then, I just check if the variable is `true` and if so, it's finished loading and I can do whatever code I want.